# Pass 4D array to lstm in keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, 4d

I have `data(X)` with a shape of (451, 4, 2, 9) where `sample number = 451`, series number in `time = 4`, `height (two series) = 2`, `width (each series has features) = 9`. So I have table 2*9 which is distributed over time.
The shape of `y` is (451, 2, 1).

my X is like :

```
array([[[2182000,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0],
        [ 416000,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0]],

       [[1724500,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0],
        [ 905000,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0]],

       [[1818500,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0],
        [ 871000,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0]],

       [[1473000,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0],
        [ 929500,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,
               0,       0]]])
```

and my y is:

```
array([[1941500],[1341500]]) #for two parallel series i have two output
```

Here is the model I want to train it:

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps,X.shape[2],X.shape[3])))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(X.shape[2],X.shape[3]))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=400, verbose=0)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = np.array([
    [[1427500,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0, 0,       0],
    [ 371000,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0, 0,       0]], 

    [[1959000,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0, 0,       0],
    [ 569000,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0, 0,       0]],

    [[2275000,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0, 0,       1],
    [ 511500,       0,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,  0,       1]], 

    [[4109000,       0,       0,       1,       0,       1,       0, 0,       1],
    [1357500,       0,       0,       1,       0,       1,       0, 0,       1]]
    ])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps,X.shape[2],X.shape[3]))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

I want to know how to pass 4d array as input in first LSTM layer, I cannot flatten it like X.shape[2]*X.shape[3] because these are two different time series(each with 9 features) and i want two different predictions for both of the time series.

Comment: what is wrong with `model.fit(X, y, epochs=400, verbose=0)` ?

Comment: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (451, 4, 2, 9)

Comment: The array needs to be 3D, you need to flatten the last two dimensions.

Comment: i cant flatten it as i have two different time series data(each with 9 features) , if i flatten it how lstm will know that these are two different time series.

Comment: if the 2 series are syncronized - treat them as single time series with 18 features. If this is something else - perhaps you need to process your data differently. Tell us more about why you need to feed 2 separate time series.

Comment: I have two different time series let say sales of product 1 and sales of product 2, i want to make one model which pass these two series in parallel and give me two  prediction for both of the product sales for next day.

Comment: Why not bring this "product" dimension to batch dimension. LSTM only will process 3D data. And having this in batch dimension, you still can predict for two products simultaneously.